# Write to StandardIn of existing process

Tags: c#

There are a lot of solution for writing to `StandardIn` of process that you start.  But I couldn't find anything for process that already exist.  Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("cgminer");                    
Process curProcess = pname[0];
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = curProcess.StandardInput;
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("q");
myStreamWriter.Flush();
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("q");
myStreamWriter.Flush();
```

So this doesn't work and throw an `StandardIn has not been redirected` error.  Any ideas?

Comment: So what happens if you redirect the current input? `pname.Options.RedirectStandardInput`?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  There is no member "option" exist for Process class.

Comment: I was doing that from memory. It's really `pname.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput`.

Comment: Ah yes, I already tried that before, it doesn't work.  StartInfo only work if you start a new process after making any changes as the same "StartInfo" suggests.